# Insect that has evolved to recognize carnivorous plants

Tags: botany

Obviously in a biome consisting of high density of carnivorous plants any insect that can recognize these plants or at least recognize organs associated with carnivory will get fitness advantage. So it seems a very natural thing to evolve from insects point of view. Has it happenned? If yes, what are some of the examples? If not, why it hasn't happened?